# Applications of Geometry of Numbers

Tags: number-theory

What are the applications of Geometry of Numbers? I think it proves the following things:

- Fermat's Christmas Theorem
- Lagrange 4-square Theorem
- Finiteness of Class Group
- Dirichlet's Unit Theorem

would love to hear about more.

Comment: Have you reviewed this: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/geometryofnumbers.pdf ? There are also several books on the topic and a Wiki page with references too.

Comment: the relevant page: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/GeometryofNumbers.html

Comment: I flagged this for community wiki but please don't make it community wiki I want to accept the notes as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you reviewed this: [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/geometryofnumbers.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/geometryofnumbers.pdf) ?

There are also several books on the topic and a Wiki page with references too.

-A

Comment: really wonderful thanks a lot

Comment: Nice reference, from our own Pete Clark, in fact!

Comment: Pete's got a really nice collection of notes (all pdf)...check out his page at the above URL, minus the "geometryofnumbers.pdf"